# how to use TDD in complex system?

Tags: javascript, tdd

So I have been making a game up to a point where I want to try TDD, so most of my working code don't have any test but I would like to try TDD for every new features.

My problem is my game comprises of tons of interdependent systems (sort of like I can't use the camera without the level in place, objects keep lots of references and initializing things take other things as argument). So just to test the fog system I need to initialize the level, the physic, the camera, the collision (because they all depend on each other to some degrees) and that create lots of duplications. Here's the code:

```
test( "shadow test", function() {
    var b2world=new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, 0), false);
    var contactListener = new collisionHandler.CollisionHandler(MASK_BITS);
    b2world.SetContactListener(contactListener);

    var map = gamejs.http.load('images/prot8.json');
    var level = new Level.Level({
        map: map, 
        size: 0.5, 
        nMaskBits: MASK_BITS.node,
        nCategoryBits: MASK_BITS.player | MASK_BITS.birdy | MASK_BITS.innerBody,
        world: b2world,
        scale: SCALE});

    var cam = new Camera.Camera({
            lvlWid: this.level.width*SCALE*this.level.blockSize, 
            lvlHei: this.level.height*SCALE*this.level.blockSize, 
            yBand: 2,
            maxSpeed: 20,
            peerWindow: new b2Vec2(350, 300),
            scrWid: scrWid, 
            scrHei: scrHei});

    var shadow = new Shadow.Shadow({
        width : 300,
        height : 300,
        level : level,
        eye : new b2Vec2(600, 600),
    });

    ok( shadow.blit, "Shadow is extended from surface" );
    ok( shadow.level, "Shadow has reference to the level" );
    ok( shadow.eye, "Shadow has reference to player's eye" );
    ok( (function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < shadow.onScreenBlocks.length; i++) {
            var rect = level.boxes[ shadow.onScreenBlocks[i] ];
            //this is half finished
        }
        return true;
    }), "Shadow do picks the blocks that are visible on screen" );
    ok( (function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < level.boxes.length; i++) if ( shadow.notProcessBlock(i) ) {
            var rect = level.boxes[i];
            if (rect.left < cam.offsetX //at this point I just realized that camera need to be setup in a more complex way...
        }
        return true;
    }), "Shadow only process those blocks that are visible on screen" );
});
```

overall it just has a bad vibe to it. It's harder to wrap my mind around and harder to maintain I think.

Comment: What is your question? Are you wanting someone to convince you to do TDD in this project? And I always considered TDD to be more relevant in complex environments, hence the desire to design against tests.

Comment: well I'm stucked. It would have been much easier if I didn't do TDD. If you can tell me a better way of writing test in such environment then I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm not planning on convincing you to do anything; it's your project, up to you what you do. There's other [software design paradigms out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_methodology), TDD may not be the most appropriate for your situation/project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When writing unit testing in a non-TDD way, you have to ask yourself for each piece of code you write: 'How can I test this'. This forces you to look at your code and make sure that all dependencies can be replaced when testing.

When doing TDD, this 'How can I test this' is baked in from the beginning. Introducing TDD in the middle of a project leads to problems when you can't replace all dependencies.

When Unit Testing, you need to make sure that you can test a unit in complete isolation and replace all dependencies with mocks or fakes. Then you can control all the inputs to your unit test so can you make sure that all code paths are tested.

To make unit testing work in your project you will have to refactor your code to really support unit testing.

I think TDD is not the main issue in this case. The question is if you want to use Unit testing at all and I think the answer to that question should be yes! Unit testing has many advantages. Now, you face the problem that the code you have written is hard to test. Making sure your code is testable is something that can be done after you've written your code but as you now experience that's quite hard. That's the point where TDD can help. TDD will make sure your code is easily testable so you can have all the benefits of unit testing.

I wrote a blog some time ago about unit testing.. maybe it can help: [Unit Testing, hell or heaven?](http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/03/unit-testing-hell-or-heaven.html)

Comment: Is TDD as relevant in single developer or small developer group contexts? What are the benefits to a programmer maintaining their own code on their own? Are there downsides (impractical, inefficient, etc.) to consider?

Comment: And I certainly agree the project would probably need to be redeveloped if it's like the OP describes. Lots of rewrites of that ambition fail, too. (Note, some time ago? That article was written a couple months ago!)

Comment: think I'll save TDD for a future project. :/

Comment: @JaredFarrish TDD is definitely a good choice, even for a single developer. As a developer, you will be forced to think about the design of your code. Good testable code is most of the time (if not always?) better code. Maybe you could say it's somewhat less efficient in the beginning but after catching your first bug trough a failing unit test you will be happy. (ps, my English isn't good enough to understand the difference between 'some time ago' and 'a couple of months ago'.. something wrong?)

Comment: No worries, I was humored by "some time ago", as I assumed you meant years back, but that wasn't the case. Do you have any suggestions for TDD information geared towards single developer or very small group? When you're the only one, too much architecture can end up being counter-productive to the total value of the result, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't see the link between TDD and 'too much architecture'. TDD emphasizes using unit testing to drive your design. Only code what you need to make your unit test succeed! This shouldn't lead to too much architecture. And your test harness will help you in refactoring your architecture as you like. I don't have any specific info on TDD as a single programmer. I would say the normal info applies even to a single developer. If you want to discuss it in more detail just send me an email :)